# menubar visible pipelight on secondray screen

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, google-chrome, moonlight

First of all, here is my setup :

- Ubuntu 13.04 on a laptop, main display is the laptop screen, secondary display is my tv
- Chrome
- Pipelight (microsoft silverlight running through wine)
- a silverlight application in the secondary display(netflix)

The problem is that, when i put netflix in fullscreen mode, the menubar remains visible on top of the secondary screen. Apparently the aplication that has focus is Microsoft Silverlight.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: one screenshot would be better.. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't take screen shots. As soon as i try, netflix/Silverlight goes out of fullscreen mode, so the problem isn't apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this behaviour comes from a modification in Compiz (my desktoip environment being Unity), wich now disallows applications on the secondary screen to go full screen.

To enable "true" fullscreen support on a secondary display, one can use the compiz configuration manager :

```
    sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

and enable the option in Utility -> Workaround -> Legacy Fullscreen Support